# GridView Databound not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView`, to which I have written a DataBound function to assign a tooltip. But it is not getting assigned. The function I have written is:

```
SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Location_Profile_Name, " + Label10.Text + " as Home_Profile FROM Home_Profile_Master", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView3.DataSource = dt;
        GridView3.DataBind();

protected void GridView3_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var gv = (GridView)sender;

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView3.Rows)
        {
            string label2 = row.Cells[2].Text.Trim();

            if (label2.Length != 0)
            {
                con.Open();
                string str = "SELECT Location_Profile_Tool_Tip FROM Location_Profile_List_ToolTip WHERE Location_Profile_Name='" + label2 + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    row.Cells[2].ToolTip = dr[0].ToString().Trim();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I debug the **label2** is null. The same code is executing for another Grid. What is wrong...!! Kindly help..!

Comment: Show a part of ASPX/ASCX where label is placed inside a row

Comment: Look at your code again you have things declared for example gv but where in the code are you using it.. ??

Comment: `label2` cannot be null, it's length can be 0 though.

Comment: But the same is working for other Grid

Comment: I have edited my question showing how I have bound my `GridView`

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... prehaps this is the problem?

```
//                          **************
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView3.Rows)
```

Should be?

```
//                          **
foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
```

**EDIT**

Ah! Cells is a zero-based array. If you want the second cell, you need to use the array index 1.

This:

```
//                        *
string label2 = row.Cells[2].Text.Trim();
```

Should be:

```
//                        *
string label2 = row.Cells[1].Text.Trim();
```

**EDIT**

Using the numeric cell index is very hard to read and very fragile. If you add a column, or remove a column, all of your code will break. I highly recommend using the cell name, like so:

```
//                  ************
string label2 = row[Label10.Text].Text.Trim();
```

**EDIT**

Maybe this would work better for you?

```
string label2 = ( (DataRow) row.DataItem )[Label10.Text].ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: Nope Cells[2], cos my first column is edit, and second Details, which is another link i have assigned, 3rd is my data for tooltip.

Comment: Are you sure that your DataBoundColumn is setup correctly? Using the correct column name?

Comment: Yea, atleast if not for that column the tooltip should be displayed for other column kw..?

Comment: I don't understand... "at least if not for that column"? If you have not databound the tooltip column correctly, then there will be no data in it. I notice that the name of the column is not known until the query is run (getting its value from Label10). If you are not setting the tooltip column's `DataField` property to the correct column at render-time, then how do you know it'll be correct?

Answer (score 0):

Having a TemplateField and then using the ID of the ItemTemplate, solves the problem.

```
protected void GridView3_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView3.Rows)
        {
            Label label1 = (Label)row.FindControl("Label1"); //ID of the ItemTemplate for my column to which I want ToolTip
            string label2 = label1.Text.Trim();

            if (label2.Length != 0)
            {
                con.Open();
                string str = "SELECT Location_Profile_Tool_Tip FROM Location_Profile_List_ToolTip WHERE Location_Profile_Name='" + label2 + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    row.Cells[2].ToolTip = dr[0].ToString().Trim();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```